# Why not use a global static logger in Java?

Tags: java, logging

It seems all Java logging solutions recommend creating a logger as a static field of class that needs to log.

Why these solutions choose logger instances and not just a single class with a handful of static methods?

What are the main benefits?

Comment: I can think of some synchronization/performance issues. All threads sharing the same global static logger would potentially have to deal or wait on other thread bad behavior. Static objects are not conducive to a dynamic feed injection modern day app? Why else, OSGI modularity is that enough to answer?

Comment: Although my question has been closed due too a very similar question made on C#, I'd argue Java and C# have enough (compile time) differences which legitimate my question on its own.